# Run a third party app inside own app on a rooted android device

Tags: android, android-intent, root

I am developing an android app for a rooted android Setup box. In my application I want to run a 3rd party application inside my application (similar to iFrames in HTML) as illustrated below

[image]

I have following questions:

1. Is it possible to run a 3rd party app inside my own app (on a **rooted device**) ?
2. Is there any code samples / project samples available ?
3. Is it possible to develop using android intents ?